# comment.create event gives me an useless comment id because I cannot make a query with it

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

I want to grab all new comments to my site and store then in my database.

I could do this accessing the opengraph api via  https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_URL} but I reckon this would give troubles when I have a lot of comments to grab.

So I though it would be better to subscrive to an event and get the comment once it was posted. So I added an event listener as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

the comment.create event gives me a commentID, but this is completely useless to me because I cant make a query for this ID.

Using the FQL I cannot search for a comment using this id, since the column post_fbid is not indexable. (as seen here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/)

I also didnt find a way to make such a query directly to the opengraph api...

Is there a way to query for a specific comment by its id?

Leo,,

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9873608/posting-comment-to-facebook-from-javascript in which the guy is able to make a fql searching the post_fbid field. I tested and it worked... why?